# Wrong encoding in json response jmeter

Tags: json, encoding, jmeter

via Jmeter I get the json response:

```
{
"status": 0,
"response": [    {
    "id": "123456789",
    "login": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxxxx",
    "system": "portal",
    "firstName": "ÃÂÃÂ»ÃÂµÃÂºÃÂÃÂµÃÂ¹",
    "middleName": "ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂ»ÃÂÃÂµÃÂ²ÃÂ¸ÃÂ",
    "lastName": "ÃÂÃÂ¾ÃÂÃÂµÃÂÃÂ¾ÃÂ²"
}]
}
```

How can I solve this problem of wrong encoding for this response? The text is russian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with last nightly build (upcoming 2.10) it  should be ok, if not report a bug.
2.10 should be released in few weeks from now.

Comment: The problem is solved but there is some problems with the support of json jmeter-plugins. When will the stable version be released?